# MS CRM installation on separate VM than SQL VM issue

Tags: sql-server, azure, dynamics-crm

I am trying to create CRM environment on Azure. Structure contains 3 VM's which are in the same Virtual Network, Cloud service and storage. First VM is deployed as ADDS with DNS, second VM has SQL Server installed on it. On the third VM, I am trying to deploy CRM full-server installation. Machines 'see' each other, firewalls are down, but during installation, I am receiving the following error concerning SQL Server:

> "This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local >server did not receive a response from an authoritative server"

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue

Answer (score 0):

Is that when trying to install Dynamics CRM so it is not able to find the SQL instance? Looks like a DNS issue. Could you double check the Host record entries in the DNS where you installed ADFS so they match the IP address given by Azure?

I had similar issues because Azure gives a Dynamic IP addresses which are not in sync with the IP in the VM.